# Can a linear and logit model have the same shape?

Tags: linear-model, binary-data, logit, dependent-variable

While I was working on an exercise based [this book](https://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/ISLR%20Seventh%20Printing.pdf), I discovered something interesting. When I fit a logit and simple linear probability model on the data (see code below), the predictions are almost identical. Intrigued by this, I decided to plot the data and discovered that the fitted lines almost overlap.

Is this pure coincidence or due to the nature of the data? I noted that the classes are not very well separated by the predictor, I assume this is the reason behind this? It would be great if someone could explain in which cases a logit model assimilates a simple linear probability model.

Here is the R code that I used:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(ISLR)

glm.fit <- glm(Direction ~ Lag2, data = Weekly, family = binomial)
Weekly$Direction <- as.numeric(Weekly$Direction)-1
lm.fit <- lm(Direction ~ Lag2, data = Weekly)

Weekly %>% ggplot(aes(x=Lag2, y=Direction)) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_smooth(method="glm", method.args=list(family="binomial"), color="#FF9999", se=FALSE) +
  geom_smooth(method=lm , color="steelblue", se=FALSE) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 1, linetype="longdash") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype="longdash") +
  geom_text(aes(x = -15,y = 0.9, label = "Up")) +
  geom_text(aes(x = 10,y = 0.1, label = "Down")) +
  xlab("% Change two days before") +
  ylab("Direction") +
  theme_classic()
```

[image: Linear Model blue, Logit Model pink]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not coincidence. It's more to do with the nature of the logistic function and to some extent the nature of the data:

The second derivative of the logistic function at the place where $p$ is $\frac12$ is $0$. There's an interval around that where the logistic function is quite close to linear; in particular if the data are such that the proportion of $1$'s stays pretty much between $0.25$ and $0.75$, the difference between a linear fit and a logistic fit in that region will tend to be quite small.

Comment: There's some related discussion in this answer: [Modelling a percentage as a dependent variable](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/388131/modelling-a-percentge-as-a-dependent-variable/388149#388149)